# Unabe to run DB2 Stored Procedure through VB script

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, db2, call

I'm breaking my head for the past three days in calling a DB2 stored procedure from VB Script. I can able to call a SP that is simple but not the one with more IN/OUT parameters.

I use the below code to add parameters for the SP.

```
oADO_CMD.CommandType = 4
oADO_CMD.CommandText = "schema.sp_name"
oADO_CMD.Parameters.Refresh

Const adVarChar = 200
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adParamOutput = 2

oADO_CMD.Parameters.append oADO_CMD.CreateParameter("test", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4, "1000")
oADO_CMD.Parameters.append oADO_CMD.CreateParameter("tester", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6, "")
```

when i run in front end i use the below query and it works fine.

```
call schema.sp_name('1000','')
```

Everything works fine in one SP but when i use the same method for another SP it just throws me error. But in front end when i give the same data, i can receive the records.

When i looked into the SP about the error im getting it is related to **preparing cursor**. Seriously i'm not sure what it is because im not very good in SP's. Is this anything about passing values from vbs to DB2 SP ?. Because there are some parameters where i need to pass empty values within double quotes.. or some other thing that causes error... ?

Here is some lines from SP.

```
CreateSQL.
------------,
    MOVE SPACES  TO lc_SQLStatement.

    EXEC SQL
    SET :lc_SQLStatement = TRIM(:lc_SelectClause)  || " " ||
                              TRIM(:lc_FromClause)    || " " ||
                              TRIM(:lc_WhereClause)
    END-EXEC.

    STRING lc_SelectClause    DELIMITED BY SIZE
    MOVE SPACES  TO lc_SQLStatement.

    EXEC SQL
    SET :lc_SQLStatement = TRIM(:lc_SelectClause)  || " " ||
                          TRIM(:lc_FromClause)    || " " ||
                          TRIM(:lc_WhereClause)
    END-EXEC.

STRING lc_SelectClause    DELIMITED BY SIZE
       lc_FromClause      DELIMITED BY SIZE
       lc_WhereClause     DELIMITED BY SIZE
INTO   lc_SQLStatement
END-STRING.

CreateDynamCursor.
-------------------
    EXEC SQL
      PREPARE cu_SearchCR FROM :lc_SQLStatement
    END-EXEC.

    EVALUATE SQLCODE
       WHEN 0
          CONTINUE
       WHEN OTHER
          MOVE lnc_04         TO pc_ReturnCode
          MOVE lnc_PrepCurErr TO pc_RetCodeDescription
    END-EVALUATE.
```

I'm getting the pc_ReturnCode and pc_RetCodeDescription values as "04" and "error while preparing cu_SearchCR".

Comment: It would help if you included the actual error text, and possibly the code of the SP...

Comment: @bhamby I have added some lines from SP. I cant paste the entire code because there are lots of select clause and JOINs used. So the issue is with **creating dynamic cursor** I guess.

Comment: Print out the contents of `lc_SQLStatement` to verify that the statement syntax is correct.